# How to bring a jQuery object into a function?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery object which I need to pull into a function, is this possible?  Please see the code snippet:

```
    var input;
    jQuery('.upload').live('click', function()
    {
    input = jQuery(this).find(".image-path");
    tb_show(title, 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');

    return false;
    }); 

    window.send_to_editor = function( html ) 
    {
         if (input)
         {
              console.log(input); // works and defined at this point...
              var data {
              action: "doFunction"
              };
              jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) 
              {
                   console.log(input); // does not work, not defined...why??
                   input.val(response); // this gives me input.val(response) is not a function
              });
         }
    }
```

Comment: As a general rule, yes, it's possible to pass and keep jquery objects. You probably have a bug in your code.

Comment: where is imageObj defined? make it var imageObj and you could be ok

Comment: are you sure it's defined before calling `post` ?

Comment: Be sure to wait (using `$(window).ready`) that your dom is ready.

Comment: @BobTodd no need for a `var` it should work (unless `jQuery(this)...` returns undefined`

Comment: Thx guys, no bugs...its just simplified to make it easier...the code runs fine...its just the imageObj that is undefined...

Comment: What's `imageObj.val(response);` supposed to do ? What is your object ?

Comment: response comes back just as "YES" passed back to the imageObj's value.

Comment: Please, give us a complete [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Is imageObj defined in the global context (the window) ?

Comment: You're doing something wrong, as this works just fine, see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/khEsn/1/) --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Major edit** now that the OP has disclosed their actual code:

The problem is that the value of `input` is not set until sometime later when the upload button is clicked, but you're trying to use that value before then, thus it's still uninitialized.  You should change your code to something like this:

```
jQuery('.upload').live('click', function()
{
    var input = jQuery(this).find(".image-path");
    if (input.length) {
        var data {
            action: "doFunction"
        }
        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
            input.val(response); // this gives me input.val(response) is not a function
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

I'm still unsure that your jQuery matches your HTML appropriately since you haven't disclosed your HTML.  Your current code is looking for an object with `class="image-path"` that is a child of the clicked on button.  That is a bit unusual form of HTML which makes me suspect your jQuery isn't right for your HTML which would be another problem to fix.

---

Original answer before the OP disclosed their actual code.

All you have to do is two things:

1. Make sure that `imageObj` is defined in the proper scope so it's available in your response callback.
2. Make sure that the jQuery object resolves to the proper type of DOM object that has a `.val()` method.  Since it's generally `<input>` objects that have a `.val()`method that works and `<input>` objects aren't usually container objects, I suspect this is at least part of your problem.

There are two ways to make sure that `imageObj` is declared in the proper scope:

1. Declare it globally so it's available as a global variable (not generally recommended).
2. Declare it in a parent scope so it's available in the callback function.  Here's an example of declaring it in a parent scope.

Like this:

```
function myFunc() {

    var imageObj = jQuery(this).parents('.image-wrapper');

    var data = {
    action: "doAjax"
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) 
    {
        imageObj.val(response); // this is undefined when run
    });  

}
```

To make sure that `imageObj` resolves to the proper type of DOM object, you can add debugging code to first check to see if `imageObj.length` is non-zero and then you need to make sure that the parent object(s) with `class="image-wrapper"` are actually `<input>` objects that have a working `.val()` method.  Since input objects usually are not container objects, this may be part of your problem.  We could advise more specifically if you showed us your HTML.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EJ8yu/

Comment: From what i know this will not work...because imageObj is in the scope of myFunc and you are using it within a user function on the callback.  I didn't show html because it is irrelevant, it could be any tag....Perhaps I made the question too complicated...I should have just asked how to pull in a jquery object into another function when it is declared outside of it.

Comment: @Rick - you are mistaken.  `imageObj` will be available from the parent scope inside the callback function.  Try it - it works.  The reason I asked you about your HTML is that half of the things you could be doing wrong relate to your HTML (as I explained in my answer).

Comment: Here's an example where it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EJ8yu/.  The only thing that will not be available inside the callback is the value of `this` from the parent scope.

Comment: Ok what if this -> var imageObj = jQuery(this).parents('.image-wrapper');
was declared outside of your example myFunc.  Then would it still work?

Comment: not sure why it isn't working for me...wondering if it has anything to do with the fact the code is wrapped inside window.send_to_editor = function( html ) {}

Comment: @Rick - we can't help much more without seeing your ACTUAL code.  We've answer the theoretical question, but it is likely different than your actual code.

Comment: Ok i have updated the OP to be more like how I have it...thanks again for your patience...

Comment: @Rick - I've added a new part to the beginning of my answer that addresses your actual code.  I still suspect their are problems with the code not matching your HTML, but without your HTML I can't offer any specific advice on that.

Comment: I thought by declaring input outside the function makes it global?  Then any functions after that can utilize it no?

Comment: It is really hard for me to paste all the code because its quite alot and it might be confusing for people because it is actually using Wordpress's media upload dialog box..I am overriding that...if people are not familiar with wordpress would not know what i am trying to do so I didn't include it.

Comment: If you look at my comments, can you please explain why it is defined in the first console.log but not the second??

Comment: `input` is a jQuery object.  If it's defined in the first `console.log()`, it will be defined in the second one unless you have code that is clearing it in between via other actions during the `.post()` call (before the callback is called).  Without code I can run and debug, I can't really tell you much more.

Comment: One other idea.  If your actual code uses an externally defined function as the third argument to `.post()` rather than an inline anonymous function defintion, then `input` would only be properly defined inside the callback function if `input` was a top-level global variable.  Again, I can't offer specifics without seeing the REAL code.  If it's a lot of code in a public web page, you can post the URL and tell us how to find the relevant code in that page.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't define imageObj in the window object. I suppose you call its definition in a function block.

This fiddle demonstrates that it works : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/fDd7P/

```
var imageObj = jQuery(".image"); // pulls <img src="#" class="image" />

function custom() {
 console.log(imageObj.attr('src')); // and this would be undefined.
}

custom(); // logs '#', type F12 to see it
```

​If you're writing `var imageObj = jQuery(".image");` in a `$(window).load(...` block, be sure to remove the `var` from this point and to declare `var imageObj;` before the `$(window).load(...` to make it global.